# How to uncheck Windows Mixed Reality Templates for Visual Studio in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

I am unable to perform [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818955/13742234) solution for error of Hololens Emulator. 
I tried looking up for **Windows Mixed Reality Templates for Visual Studio** while installation of Visual Studio 2017, but I didn't got that. Can someone please tell me where would I get that?

I also tried to install it from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WindowsMixedRealityteam.WindowsMixedRealityAppTemplatesVSIX), for both Visual Studio 2019 and 2017, but it didn't solved the error of Hololens Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Not Visual Studio, but while installing the HoloLens emulator, uncheck **[Windows Mixed Reality Templates for Visual Studio]** in the step **[Select the features you want to install]**. As shown below:

[image]